# Passport strategy for authenticating with LinkedIn using the OAuth 2.0a API return undefined email on save User

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Unable to retrieve the user email on LinkedIn. I have used passport-LinkedIn and OAuth 2.0. I can interpolate the username and picture. This is the code that I have tried.

```
var LinkedIn = require('passport-linkedin-oauth2').Strategy;

module.exports = (passport, User) => {
    passport.use( new LinkedIn({
        clientID: '86ew637ipvirsa',
        clientSecret: 'HoEMfqCBGL9SxsIt',
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/linkedin/callback'
        }, (accesstoken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        User.findOne({'linkedin.id': profile.id}, (err, x) => {
            if (x) return done(null, x);
            var user = {
                displayName: profile.displayName,
                image: profile._json.pictureUrl,
                email: profile.emailAddress,
                linkedin: {
                    id: profile.id
                }
            };
            User.create(user);
            User.create(user, (err, x) => done(null, x));
        });
    }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the npm package being used by you is not properly documented. The author has not explicitly said how you can access the email field from the profile variable.

You can pass in the scope with strategy and get the email fields by logging the profile variable.

```
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
clientID: LINKEDIN_KEY,
clientSecret: LINKEDIN_SECRET,
callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/linkedin/callback",
scope: ['r_emailaddress', 'r_basicprofile'], //pass the scope
state: true
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
// asynchronous verification, for effect... 
  process.nextTick(function () {
     console.log(profile); //logging
     return done(null, profile);
  });
}));
```

You can also use another [package](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-linkedin#profile-fields) . Here you can explicitly define the profile fields you want to access.